# The origin of a phrase "deep sea diver"

Tags: phrase-meaning

Why is a banknote of 5 Pounds sometimes called "a deep sea diver"? I delved into the Internet but found nothing.

Comment: Who says it is? Context, please.

Comment: Rhyming slang.  Lady Godiva = Fiver, etc

Comment: Try some [research](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=five+pound+note+deep+sea+diver)

Comment: Your new question is very different from your original question, which means @Darth's answer no longer makes sense. You should restore your original question and ask a new one. (Or not, as your new question will likely be closed as off-topic.)

Comment: Ironically, you have made your question much worse. There was nothing wrong with your original question except that it's better to say where and in what context you heard a phrase, since an isolated "what does this word mean" is sometimes hard to identify.  A focused question about a specific phrase is a good question; a vague "hey what's some fun stuff?" is not appropriate for Stack.

Comment: I've rolled back.  If you want to ask a new question please do so, but don't edit this question to ask a new question.  However your new question "please tell me the history of rhyming slang") is off topic. It isn't about learning English.  You may try asking it at [English.se]  but please do some general research first.

Answer (score 1):

It's Cockney rhyming slang. "Deep sea diver" rhymes with "fiver", slang for a five-pound note.

In rhyming slang, you replace a word (originally, a word you're trying to avoid saying because it's crude or illegal) with a two or three word phrase that rhymes with it, and then optionally drop the rhyming word. Most of rhyming slang is understood entirely by rote; you can't usually figure it out without already knowing what it means.

A famous (clean) example is instead of "stairs" you could say "apples and pears", or just "apples" -- as in "Go out back and I'll meet you by the apples."

Comment: I was unaware of *rhyming slang*.  Thank you for chairing.

Comment: @EllieK I'm glad that my question seems to be interesting even for Americans (I'm a newbie here and it doesn't add up to me why somebody could have downvoted it?).

Comment: @Jaysson Some people figure that if they can come up with a google search that immediately answers the question, you shouldn't have asked it; but this ignores differences in the algorithmic search results based on your search history, your nation of origin, and for that matter just personal differences in skill for choosing highly effective search terms.  Still, it would help to say where and in what context you heard the term.

Comment: @Darth Pseudonym Thank you. I will try to edit my question to make it more interesting, maybe.